# SiriKit iOS13 - Siri Dialog not coming

Tags: ios, ios13, sirikit

I am integrating SiriKit into my iOS 13 app.

For that I am using [Apple's Sample app - Soup Chef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/soup_chef_accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts) for understanding it.

In my Custom Intent, I have selected `Ask Each Time` in Shortcuts App for quantity value.

[image]

But, When I run the shortcut from `Hey, Siri!`, it redirect me to `Shortcuts App`, instead of **Siri asking me about quantity.**

I have `Siri Dialog` enabled already.
[image]

How can I force Siri to ask me the question, instead of getting redirected to Shortcuts App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue in iOS13.0. Try running this on a device running iOS13.1, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

SiriKit stopped using Siri Dialog prompts (iOS13.1)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122235

Apple is in the process of integrating the new version of Siri. So it deactivates some features.